# How to compile fortran files in an QT Project under OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, fortran

I have an QT project with some fortran code included. Its working fine in Linux and Windows. But in OSX its not compiling and saying :

```
error: invalid value 'f95' in '-x f95'
```

Which i guess is because clang/gcc version which comes with XCode does not include fortran.

I am using MacOSX10.11 with LLVM 7.3.0(clang-703.0.31) and QT 5.6